# AIDE is taking forever to initialize

Tags: cron, aide

I have a server at home that I use as a NAS and some other services. The server has Debian Jessie on it, with 4x 4 TB harddrives in RAID5. I use this server to store all my home data, movies, games, etc. About 75% of it is filled.

I learned about AIDE some time ago after checking my cron reports, with aide giving an error:

```
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/aide exited with return code 1
/etc/cron.daily/tripwire:
### Error: File could not be opened.
### Filename: /var/lib/tripwire/myhostname.twd
### No such file or directory
### Exiting...
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/tripwire exited with return code 8
```

So to initialize my cron database, I executed the command: `sudo aideinit` [according to this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-software-integrity-checking-with-aide/). However, this command has been running for the last two days!!!

I noticed that it's scanning the whole server including my whole RAID array! This I learned because it gave stdout messages related to the data in my RAID. Part of them are the following:

```
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_PistolP.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_M290P.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_FP9A5Pickups.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_NRP57P.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_M290S.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_R78S.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_A42S.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_MRT6Clip.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_EKS43S.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/BallisticStripe2.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_M50Clip.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/BallisticGoldLogo.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_Rockets.jpg mtime in future
/raidarray/Games/UT2004/Help/BallisticFiles/Render_M925S.jpg mtime in future
```

So what's going on? I'm quite new to AIDE, but I would like to understand how it works. Should it really take that long? Does it make sense for it to scan my whole RAID array? How would you manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution is to exclude that directory of the array. This is how to exclude it: Just add this line to the config file of aide to exclude the folder `/raidarray`:

```
!/raidarray/.*
```